# Windows 8 app GroupedItemsPage - Adding Items

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I'm using a GroupedItemsPage based off of the template in Visual Studio. A SampleDataSource is provided, so I used that as an example and created my own data source. However, I want to add items to the grid view that are downloaded off the internet asynchronously. The problem is, once I get the results back and process them and add them to the Data source, the screen isnt updated to show the new Grid Pages.

Here is my `LoadState` method on the GroupedItemsPage class:

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
            // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
            var h = DataModel.MainPageDataSource.GetSingleton().GetGridGroups("AllGroups");
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = h;
        }
```

Here is my data source class:

```
class MainPageDataSource : FacepunchWin8.Common.BindableBase
    {
        public static MainPageDataSource _singleton = new MainPageDataSource();
        public static MainPageDataSource GetSingleton() { return _singleton; }

        private static Uri _baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///");
        private ObservableCollection<MainPageGrid> _gridGroups = new ObservableCollection<MainPageGrid>();




        void IndexParserComplete(HTMLParser p)
        {
            HTMLParserIndex parser = p as HTMLParserIndex;
            foreach (ForumSection f in parser.GetForumSections())
            {
                MainPageGrid forumGrid = new MainPageGrid(f.Title(), f.Title());

                _gridGroups.Add(forumGrid);

            }


        }

        private void ItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public MainPageDataSource()
        {
            HTMLParserIndex parser = new HTMLParserIndex();
            parser.SetComplateDelegate(IndexParserComplete);
            Scraper.GetSingleton().RequestForumIndex(parser);
            MainPageGrid Grid1 = new MainPageGrid("GRID1", "TestPage");
            Grid1.Items.Add(new MainPageGridItem("Grid00", "GridOne", "Subtitle", "Assets/DarkGray.png"));

            _gridGroups.Add(Grid1);



        }
        public ObservableCollection<MainPageGrid> GetGridGroups(string uniqueId)
        {
            if (!uniqueId.Equals("AllGroups")) throw new ArgumentException("Only 'AllGroups' is supported as a collection of groups");

            return _gridGroups;
        }


    }
```

The constructor creates some items much like the `SampleDataSource`, which show up properly on the screen. However, after the data is downloaded from the internet, `IndexParserComplete` is called, which adds some new items to _gridGroups. How can I notify the GroupedItemsPage to refresh the screen and re-read the data from the data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer. Turns out modifying the ObservableCollection from another thread/setting the data source from another thread is not supported. Since I was adding data from an Asynchronous operation, I needed to use a Dispatcher to add the data using the main UI thread.

`_gridGroups.Add(forumGrid);` in `IndexParserComplete(HTMLParser p)` I replaced with:

```
 this._uiDispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
               {
                    DataModel.MainPageDataSource.GetSingleton().AddPageGrid(forumGrid);
               })
```

where _uiDispatcher = `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher`;